# Вывод данных mysql+php

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, вывод

Имеется таблица klienti, в ней поля: klient,op_forma,naimen и т.д. сейчас данные выводятся в столбик,а надо в строку.Помогите пожалуйста. Вот код:

```
<?php 
$connection=mysql_connect("localhost","reklama","reklama") ;
$db=mysql_select_db(reklama);
mysql_set_charset("utf8");

if (!$connection || !$db)
{
exit(mysql_error());
}

$rezult=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM klienti");
mysql_close();

//пока что-то есть в массиве,выводить
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($rezult))
{?>

<table class="table1">

<th>Информация о клиентах</th>
<tr class="tr1"><td>Клиент:<?php echo $row['klient']?></tr></td>
<p><tr class="tr1"><td>ОП форма: <?php echo $row['op_forma']?></tr></td> </p>
<p><tr class="tr1"><td>Наименование: <?php echo $row['naimen']?></tr></td> </p>
<p><tr class="tr1"><td>Отрасль: <?php echo $row['otrasl']?> </tr></td></p>
<p><tr class="tr1"><td>Телефон: <?php echo $row['telefon']?></tr></td> </p>
<p><tr class="tr1"><td>Email: <?php echo $row['email']?> </tr></td></p>
<p><tr class="tr1"><td>Контактное лицо: <?php echo $row['kont_lico']?></tr></td> </p>
<p><tr class="tr1"><td>Должность: <?php echo $row['dolznost']?> </tr></td></p>
<?php } ?>  
</table>
```

Comment: Тогда в гугле посмотрите как в HTML строится таблица, которую вы используете. Нужно в строку - так и делайте в строку, т.е. в одном блоке `<tr></tr>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала, у вас теги неправильно расставлены

`<tr><td></tr></td>` а должно быть `<tr><td></td></tr>`

А то что нужно вам, строится следующим образом:

```
<table class="table1" border="1">
  <tr>Информация о клиентах</tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Клиент</td>
    <td>ОП форма</td>
    <td>Наименование</td>
    ...
    ...
  <tr>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['']?></td>
    ...
    ... 
  </tr>
</table>
```

p.s. [Почитайте про таблицы](http://htmlbook.ru/html/table)